# Stream.write() only works once per method

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a method that sends a message to a client as seen below. But if I call this method twice once after another it won't work properly and the data seems to have never been sent at all.

I added some comments below to show the issue.

```
public static void SendRequestInformation(Client target, int messageId)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = target.getClientSocket().GetStream();
        byte[] byteData = null;
        switch (messageId)
        {
            case 0:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ping");
                break;
            case 1:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("handshake");
                break; 
            case 3:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("osif");
                break;
            case 4:
                byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("idle");
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ClientHandle.RemoveFromClientPool(target, "Unable to reach Client"); 
        }
    }

// so if here I have a method like...
private void onRefreshMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        if (mi != null)
        {
            ContextMenu cm = mi.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
            if (cm != null)
            {
                Grid g = cm.PlacementTarget as Grid;
                if (g != null)
                {

                    var p = Mouse.GetPosition(g);

                    int row = 0;
                    int col = 0;
                    double accumulatedHeight = 0.0;
                    double accumulatedWidth = 0.0;

                    // calc row mouse was over
                    foreach (var rowDefinition in g.RowDefinitions)
                    {
                        accumulatedHeight += rowDefinition.ActualHeight;
                        if (accumulatedHeight >= p.Y)
                            break;
                        row++;
                    }
                    Client c = getRowClient(row);
                    if (c != null)
                    {
//the below two lines seem to not be called if called only the top one seems to work 
                        ConnectionHandle.SendRequestInformation(c, 1);
                        ConnectionHandle.SendRequestInformation(c, 4);
                    }
                    else
                        if (debugWindow != null)
                            debugWindow.LogTextBox.AppendText("Unable to find client!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should elaborate on "won't work properly". Exceptions? Is the first write successful and CanWrite false subsequently? Are you closing the socket somewhere else? etc..

Comment: I seem to not be getting any exceptions thrown. The try around stream.write is not catching anything. What I mean by not working properly is that it doesn't send two requests. It works if I call the method not back to back.

Comment: Any reason why SendRequestInformation method marked as static? Also try adding stream.Close() after flushing.

Comment: Do you realize that at the receive end you may be receiving multiple packets in a single receive operation? For that reason network stream data should be more self-describing, for example by prefixing each packet with the length of the packet. Then it's easier to process the packets at the other end.

Comment: Barring more information, I'd guess that Rennie's suggestion has the problem pegged. You don't explain what makes you think that "it doesn't send two requests", but the most obvious explanation is that your receiving code doesn't notice that two requests were made.